# Center text independent of number of lines

Tags: html, css, centering

Is it possible to build a css system which will allow a paragraph to center in a page independent of window width? Meaning that as you make the window smaller and the number or lines increases, it will auto adjust to still be centered in the page.

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycxch17b/)

And here's the existing system:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10em;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.title {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}

.paragraph {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the problem with the current demo? It seems to work for me. The only thing is that it seems a little too high on the page, but this can be adjusted with simple positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good reference for centering things https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

You can use `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to put something in the center.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #9ab;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}
.paragraph {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">TITLE</div>
  <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum voluptas, voluptatibus in accusamus alias voluptatem facilis omnis saepe laudantium, dolorem, nobis modi ratione est doloremque hic enim beatae fugit sapiente!</div>
</div>
```

You can also use flexbox with `align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #9ab;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}
.paragraph {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">TITLE</div>
  <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum voluptas, voluptatibus in accusamus alias voluptatem facilis omnis saepe laudantium, dolorem, nobis modi ratione est doloremque hic enim beatae fugit sapiente!</div>
</div>
```